# How to convert an SVG file to Base64String/JPG/PNG in NativeScript to use in Img Tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to display an SVG Image on my NativeScript app. And there are multiple ways I found to do so.

1. The first way I found is to convert from SVG to Base64String. Then that Base64String can be converted to PNG/JPG to display, such as below:

   `let baseString = "someBaseString";`

   `let imageFromBase64String = ImageSource.fromBase64Sync(baseString);`

But the problem is this only works if we already have a Base64String made from an SVG File, and I cannot find a way to convert from SVG to Base64String at the first place.

2. The second way to I found is the following, using `URL.createObject()`

   ```
    if (svgDoc != null || svgDoc != undefined) {
        let blob = new Blob([svgDoc], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let sanitzed = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
    }
   ```

And then to use the created `sanitized` link in the <img src""> tag.
But the problem is that this only works in Angular Web apps and not in NativeScript.

Any kind of information would be helpful.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

in nativescript image should be requested through the [getImage](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_http_.html#getimage) method of http.

Comment: Can you give an example using Blob object OR similar way to create a secure url of a private image and using that to getImage?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best result you can get it using a library that transform the svg to canvas, see [this one](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) from DanGreen. Another option is this another one [this link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/draw-an-svg-to-canvas-and-download-it-as-image-in-javascript-f7f7713cf81f).

I made a simple example with the two approachs in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6yfvnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you has a svg and a two canvas

```
<svg #svg...>
</svg>
<canvas #canvas></canvas>
<canvas #canvas2></canvas>

  @ViewChild('svg', { static: true }) svg;
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true }) canvas;
  @ViewChild('canvas2', { static: true }) canvas2;
  v: any;
  async ngOnInit() {
    const svgElement = this.svg.nativeElement;
    const { width, height } = svgElement.getBBox();
    const clonedSvgElement = svgElement.cloneNode(true);
    const outerHTML = clonedSvgElement.outerHTML,
      blob = new Blob([outerHTML], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });

    const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    const blobURL = (URL as any).createObjectURL(blob);
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => {
      let canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;

      canvas.width = width;

      canvas.height = height;
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      // draw image in canvas starting left-0 , top - 0
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height); //
      //downloadImage(canvas); //need to implement};
    };
    image.src = blobURL;
    const ctx = this.canvas2.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.v = await Canvg.fromString(
      ctx,
      '<svg><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a7 7 0 1 0 14 0A7 7 0 0 0 1 8zm15 0A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-4.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5z"/></svg>'
    );

    this.v.start();
  }
```

Comment: How is this even related to NativeScript?